Charging Ni-MH batteries
I understand that the recommended charging voltage for AA/AAA NI-MH batteries is between 1.4 V to 1.6 V and c/10 charging current.
If i need to choose between 2 options:

Charging voltage of 1.4 V and charging current of c/5
Charging voltage of 1.6 V and charging current of c/10

Which option will cause less stress to the battery and extend
there life?
I know that a good sophisticated charger is the best as it is charging the batteries while it take into account some factors, checks temperature, state of charge etc.
But now I would like to understand what option is preferable and why?

You can't set charging voltage and current simultaneously. This sounds like an XY problem or you are misinterpreting a datasheet. Where are these numbers coming from?

Typically the charging current is controlled and the battery voltage is whatever the battery has at that charging current (will increase as the battery becomes charged).  A C/10 rate would likely give longer battery life than a C/5.  But note that the current must drop to a very low value once the battery is charged, otherwise it will overheat and be damaged.

This is a theoretical question.I haven't used any datasheet and I know that lower charging current will give longer battery life.I would like to know the voltage impact on the battery vs the current.whether raising the charging voltage with lower charging current is better(for battery life)than higher charging current at lower charging voltage?of course,in the accepted values.For example:charging the battery at 2v with C/30 charging current vs charging the battery at 1.4v at c/2 charging current.You may see it as theoretical question.

You can't set voltage and current separately. The charging current at a given terminal voltage depends on the state of charge.

You MAY means either "Charge at C/5 until 1.4 V is teached" OR "Charge at C/10 until 1.6V is reached". || C/10 is gentler BUT you will need to find an endpoint voltage that best suits your cells. || You do not say what the cell type is (AA etc) This can matter. || For AA NiMH C/10 to 1.45V works well for most AA brands (I used about 1 million AA NiMH :-) .

@Russell McMahon,thank you for the correction.This is exactly what i meant in my question(charge at...until...is reached).I update my question(NI-MH batteries AA/AAA).So if i set the charger at higher voltage,lets say even 1.8V and the current will be set,as low as C/10,even that the charging current will be very low,it is better to set to an higher charging currents with 1.4V,than a low charging currents with 1.8V,right?of course,we are talking about the setting of the max. current and voltage,while the voltage and the current will be changed during the charging according to the battery state

@Dan  The current is very very very usually fixed at eg C/10 and the voltage rises unil the end point is reached. || Endpoint voltage and charge rate are reasonably imdependent and you should not tie them together in your specification *UNLESS you have acomptent information source that says to do so AND WHY.|| Where did you get those figures from?|| You need to answer my question -are you REALLY using NiCd or maybe NiMH. If NiCd then WHY? What environment. What mAH. I'd suggest C/10 and then find and endpoint tat does what you want with the batteries you are using. BECAUSE this is not the ..

... safest and most ceri=tain method of NiCd charging. Temperature can have a result AND if Vterminate is too gigh for a given C rate you can get runaway where the V set is never reached and the cell is boiled dry over time. || Knowing more about your application would help. There are other charging algorithms - why are you using this one? || I used this one in hundreds of thousands of products BECAUSE of the environment/application/circumstances BUT it's not usually the best choice. || What are you trying to achieve.

@Russell,I don't know why do you think i use NiCd.I mentioned in my question's title,in my question itself and in my comments only the ni-mh batteries(and added the AA/AAA size later).I took the figures after browsing the web,which says that you can charge ni-mh batteries at voltage 1.4V-1.6V(max 1.8V)and current around c/5-c/10.So,i was trying to understand what can be wrose:to charge the battery when the voltage set to an higher voltage(until it reaches 1.8V)with low current setting(c/10)or to charge the battery when the voltage set to low voltage(until...1.4v)but set at higer current(c2).

@Dan  My mistake - I was sure I saw NiCd mentioned BUT I see I was wrong. I'm pleased that you mean NimH. || Having used 1,000,000+ NimH AA cells I dislike them severely when charged in the way you describe. It's doable but better is to either use a custom NiMH targetered charger IC IF the application allows it OR use eg LiIon or LiFeP$. Both these are vastly easier to manage well. || I used NiMHbecause the client insisted and I useda C/10 & 1.45V termination system with added current / voltage tailoring because my application did not allow the more usual charge methods.

The type of battery is not really my concern,the idea of the influence of the charging current and charging voltage values(as i described before)is what i was trying to figure-up.Thanks for your response.

@Dan The type of battery is utterly foundational in answering the question. Even within the NiMH family AA cells under about 1800 mAh could be slow trickle charged at end of cha=rging but ones above that capacity would die underANY degree of ongoing charge. In the last few years there MAY have been changes made which again allow slow end of charge ongoing charge rates. This is all due to having or not having recombination structures and chemicals which convert electrolysed H2 and O2 back to water. ||  ...

... If you charge at C/10 and aim for a 1.8V endpoint the call may cook forever. Again. C/10 and 1.45V at room temperature is reasonably safe. |||| I'd expect based on my experiences that C/5 and 1.4V endpoint would be VERY safe BECAUSE the cell would not reach full charge.

Thanks,Russell,i guess i got the idea.

You have some misunderstanding. You can't simultaneously set battery current and voltage. Because the voltage over the cell is what it is when you send current through it, and as the cell charges, the voltage over it will rise. Sophisticated quick chargers monitor the voltage and can determine when the cell is full when voltage starts to drop instead of rise. And the cell likely is not full at 1.4V or maybe not at 1.6V either.
When you buy a cell, these things like typical curves for voltages and currents are in the data sheet.

I'm pretty sure that all of the higher-end NiMH chargers also measure the temperature of each cell. ISTR somebody telling me that stopping the charge when the cell temperature starts to rise is a better strategy than stopping it at any fixed voltage threshold.

As others mentioned, these numbers are limits to that parameters, not exact settings.
Usually a battery charger goes through 2~3 phases of:

CC (Constant Current) mode: In this mode, the charger sets a limit usually around the maximum cell voltage, but lowers it constantly in order to keep the current in pre-defined values. If you connect a 2V depleted battery into a 4.2V charger, and the battery internal resistance is 0.1 ohms, the current would be around 20 Amps.It is obviously not acceptable. So the charger tries to lower until the current stays at safe values then it raises the voltage, as the battery charges up and cell voltage goes higher.
CV (Constant Voltage) mode: In this mode, the battery cell voltage is close the the maximum and there is no need to lower the voltage. Instead the voltage is kept at 4.2V and just monitors the current for short circuits and extremely unwanted situations.

So these numbers you mentioned are just limits to that parameters. 1.4V and C/5 means different on CC or CV cases:

Keep the voltage exactly at 1.4V, if the current goes over C/5 shut down the device and consider it an error (CV mode)
Keep the current below C/5 at all times, and raise the voltage as the cell voltage goes up, but stop at a maximum of 1.4v (CC mode)

